# React Native Android App Crashes on Launch - Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1

Tags: android, react-native

**Error Logcat
**

**E/unknown:ReactNative: Tried to remove non-existent frame callback

W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class org.reactnative.maskedview.RNCMaskedViewManager
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class expo.modules.kotlin.views.GroupViewManagerWrapper
W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class expo.modules.kotlin.views.SimpleViewManagerWrapper

D/OpenGLRenderer: --- Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x6675427961727259 in tid 15808 (mqt_js), pid 15526 (mona.---app)
**

I have tried all solutions on StackOverflow:

1)Cold Boot & Wipe Data
2)Restarted Device and Invalidate Caches
3)Disabled Stack.Screen animation
4)Adding "x86" to "abiFilters"
5)Uninstall and reinstall the app.
6)Disabled Hermes in build.gradle

None of these worked

Comment: You should post an example of what you are trying to do, so that other developers may try to reproduce the error, from the question it is not clear. Ragards

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just run the app. It immediately crashing after start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. You need to run expo prebuild --clean. This will delete and re-generate the native project files from scratch.